# How do I add a source IP range in an AWS security group?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I can add IPs in the form x.x.x.x/24. But how do I add a range of say 50 IPs? It seems silly typing them all in!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Security Groups expect CIDR notation. Hopefully, depending on the range you're talking about, you can find a CIDR block that matches most of them, but for the outliers, you'll need to add them manually.

For the future, try and design your network around subnets instead of "ranges".

Comment: Its a whitelist to unblock a set of static IPs that the ISP has issued. Unfortunately I dont have control of that. They are like x.x.x.51 - x.x.x.250

Comment: @GodAtum If you're not working on something insanely secure, `x.x.x.0/24` will whitelist x.x.x.0 - x.x.x.255. If you really need it to be .51 - .250, use something like http://www.ipaddressguide.com/cidr#range to get the list (in your example, `x.x.x.51/32 x.x.x.52/30 x.x.x.56/29 x.x.x.64/26 x.x.x.128/26 x.x.x.192/27 x.x.x.224/28 x.x.x.240/29 x.x.x.248/31 x.x.x.250/32`).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it's related to your use case, but what we do is that clients need to be connected to a VPN in order to access a certain service on a server, e.g. RDP. The VPN server has a elastic IP and therefore I only need to add one IP address to the security group for this service (e.g. RDP).

Comment: Can you add the VPN service into the server you're trying to protect? Or does this VPN have to exist on an external server?